# LWC - error adding a targetConfigs into metadata (The 'targetConfig' tag doesn't support text.)

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have the following `js-meta.xml` file for a lightning component. When I save this I get an error:

> The 'targetConfig' tag doesn't support text.

What is the solution for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
        <targets>
            <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
            <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
        </targets>
        <targetConfigs>
            <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">​
                <property name="recordId" label="Record Id" type="String" />
            </targetConfig>
        </targetConfigs>
    </LightningComponentBundle>
```

Without the `targetConfigs` node there are no problems.

Note: What I'm trying to do is take an existing working component from a Record page and allow it to be run from within a flow. I believe I need to pass in the `recordId` to the component to get the data wired correctly.

Comment: Try using a different property name than the standard `recordId` parameter

Comment: Sadly still same error with 'lorem' as the parameter name. Will try rebuilding meta file from scratch and also try with another component to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annoyingly(?) the answer was to retype the metadata from scratch - the same format and parameter names, etc... worked so may have been an issue with copy/paste into VSCode from the net.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `default="{!recordId}"` to the  tag's directives

```
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <property
            name="recordId"
            type="String"
            label="Record Id"
            description="Automatically bind the page's record id to the component variable"
            default="{!recordId}" />
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Refresh the visual studio code by using command " workbench.action.reloadWindow ", that will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have copy pasted from developer guide, you would find a junk character in this line, espcially in the end - so try removing `>` and type again. You can also check from https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector (atleast I found the junk character using this tool)

```
<targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">​
```